# Not sure what's wrong with Python Class Code

Tags: python

I'm still getting my head around classes in Python,

```
class Triangle(object):
    def __init__(self, angle1, angle2, angle3):
        angle1 = self.angle1
        angle2 = self.angle2
        angle3 = self.angle3
    number_of_sides = 3
    def check_angles(angle1, angle2, angle3):
        if angle1+angle2+angle3 == 180:
            return True
        else:
            return False

my_triangle = Triangle(30, 60, 90)
print(Triangle.number_of_sides)
print(Triangle.check_angles)
```

So what's wrong?

Stackoverflow has some really mean users, I come from MathStackExchange and people didn't downvote novice/noob questions as much as they do here.

Comment: Quite a few things, actually.

Comment: Check angles now expects three parameters.

Comment: Could simply be because more novices are trying to learn Python than math...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have your assignments backward:

```
self.angle1 = angle1
```

etc.

Thinking about what is going on a little bit might help here.  `self` is an instance of the class `Triangle` that is passed in.  So,

```
T = Triangle()
T.method_call()  #basically the same as `Triangle.method_call(T)`
```

Within `method_call`, `self` is a reference to `T`.  (`__init__` is kind of magic -- It gets called automatically on the first line, but the principle is still the same).  Once you know that, it's easy to see why you need `self.whatever = whatever` -- You're putting a new attribute on the object `T`!
Finally, this explains how you should write `check_angles`:

```
def check_angles(self):
    #remember, `self` is a reference to a triangle instance -- T in our hypothetical code
    #so we can use `self` to gain access to all the attributes we set in `__init__`.
    if self.angle1 + self.angle2 + self.angle3 == 180:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

---

Now a quick diversion into class attributes.  You can put attributes onto a *class* as well:

```
class Triangle:
    number_of_sides = 3
```

I think it is customary to define class attributes before you define your methods (functions), but you don't actually have to.  (It will help the readers of your code understand it though -- I misunderstood your original code because of the order you did things).

You can dynamically add attributes to a class after the class has been created as well:

```
class Triangle:
    ...

Triangle.number_of_angles = Rhombus.number_of_angles - 1
```

You can get access to `Triangle.some_attribute` a few ways.  The first way is directly through the class (`Triangle.number_of_sides`).  The second way is via an instance:

```
T = Triangle()
T.number_of_sides
```

This seems a little funny at first.  After all, the instance doesn't have a `number_of_sides` attribute.  It turns out that python is designed to look at the instance **first** to see if it has it's own `number_of_sides` attribute.  If it does, great, that's what you get.  If it doesn't however, python will then look at the class for the attribute.  This turns into a handy way to share data between instances of a class.

Comment: Thank you! I thought that when assigning variables, that it didn't matter whether the variable was on the left or the right of the equal sign.

Comment: @algebr -- The order of the assignment matters (and it matters a lot!)   :-).  Happy coding.

Comment: Your comment about `number_of sides` as an instance attribute is wrong - you can still access it via `T.number_of_sides` if it's a class attribute. In this case I'd prefer it as a class attribute because it's constant, so it doesn't make much sense to duplicate it in every instance.

Comment: @l4mpi -- You're right.  I was just assuming it was an indentation error in `__init__`

Comment: @mgilson glad I could help - correcting someone with 4k python upvotes is always a pleasure :)

Comment: @l4mpi -- Not 4k yet ;-).  I think I'm only at 3.6k or something like that ... Eventually though.  For the record though, there are lots of people around here who know *A LOT* more python than I do with many fewer upvotes ... I just happen to waste a lot of time here ... :-)

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant to write the constructor like this:

```
class Triangle(object):
    def __init__(self, angle1, angle2, angle3):
        self.angle1 = angle1
        self.angle2 = angle2
        self.angle3 = angle3
```

Answer (score 1):

Im guessing this is the Python Koans exercise. Great library and good luck!

I believe you have two problems.

first is assignments. self is on the left side.

second is your method creation. you need to pass the self variable and reference the attributes as such

```
class Triangle(object):
    def __init__(self, angle1, angle2, angle3):
        self.angle1 = angle1
        self.angle2 = angle2
        self.angle3 = angle3
        self.number_of_sides = 3
    def check_angles(self):
        if self.angle1 + self.angle2 + self.angle3 == 180:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Answer (score 1):

Without a lot of explanation so you can learn from it yourself, here's a way to write your class and use it that will work:

```
class Triangle(object):
    def __init__(self, angle1, angle2, angle3):
        self.angle1 = angle1
        self.angle2 = angle2
        self.angle3 = angle3
    number_of_sides = 3
    def check_angles(self):
        return self.angle1+self.angle2+self.angle3 == 180

my_triangle = Triangle(30, 60, 90)
print(Triangle.number_of_sides)
print(my_triangle.check_angles())
```

Output:

```
3
True
```